# jQuery UI onchange each loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

What I'm trying to achieve is when the list of textareas is rearranged that the name of the textareas updates to always be ordered ascending. To demonstrate:

Original

```
name      content
value[0]  content0
value[1]  content1
value[2]  content2
```

Reordered (not necessarily in this order, just an example)

```
name      content
value[0]  content2
value[1]  content0
value[2]  content1
```

What I've written should loop through the list and update the name attributes, but sometimes it just doesn't and the other times it will get the order of the names very wrong. Here's the jQuery I'm running:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".sortable" ).on("sortchange", function( event, ui ) {
        var $i = 0;
        $('.sortable > li').each(function(){
            $(this).children('textarea').attr( 'name', 'value[' + $i + ']' );
            $i++;
        });
    });
});
```

[And a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cameronjonesweb/kz4t8ph5/1/). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You could access the `textarea` elements by index, or using DOM traversal, and negate the need for clunky incremental attribute all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use *sortstop* instead of *sortchange*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".sortable" ).on("sortstop", function( event, ui ) {
        var $i = 0;
        $('.sortable > li').each(function(){
            $(this).children('textarea').attr( 'name', 'value[' + $i + ']' );
            $i++;
        });
    });
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kz4t8ph5/2/

Also take a look at Saif's answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

use `sortupdate` instead of `sortchange`. `sortchange` is triggered  during sorting that's why you are getting unexpected number sequence. `sortupdate` will be triggered when you stopped sorting. so you will get the final position and expected sequence.

```
$( ".sortable" ).on("sortupdate", function( event, ui )
{
}
```